# VUE JS- How Do You Run Pre Created Vue Js Code?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a folder of Vue js code shared from someone, but I can't run it. I normally use 'yarn serve' when I create a new project, however, yarn serve doesn't work seeing that 'I didn't create it' (using Vue Cli).

Again how can I run this code???

Comment: Hi, Can you share the package.json file? also, did you run `npm install` or `yarn install` before run the project?

Comment: Is there a `README.md` file in the *"folder of Vue js code"*?

Comment: I figured it out, use "npm install"

Answer (score 2):

check if there is a package json file then:

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the assist, 'npm install ' & 'npm run dev ' was the appropriate command.

Answer (score 0):

1. install all required packages from package.json: `npm i`
2. serve: `yarn serve`

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm for it as everyone said.Go through your README.md or First config your system. then

```
$npm install
$npm run serve
```